# Magento - Limit form submission per client

Tags: php, forms, magento

In the site I'm working on, there's a section where the client can rate the website and get a coupon.

In order to prevent them to vote multiple times, how could I limit their submissions to just one time?

I wouldn't like to use cookies because they could be erased, but rather I was thinking about the

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
```

method, I could set a sort of variable to check if he voted already or not.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: It is rather tricky doing this without cookies. The most obvious alternative is using an IP-address, possibly together with the user agent, but that has its own set of challenges. Perhaps you should only let registered users vote, and check against their profile to see whether they are allowed to cast a vote.

Comment: And indeed only registered users can vote, I already show the message "You need to be registered to cast a vote".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`And indeed only registered users can vote, I already show the message "You need to be registered to cast a vote"`
Then you can create a module with a model, and installation sql to add a new table (where you can save the customer id and coupon granted to that customer) and if they cast multiple votes or change their vote, you can give the same coupon every time.

Also if the coupon is generated using a Catalog Rule, then you can limit the number of `Uses per Customer` to 1 (the customer group can also be specified only for logged in users - depends on what groups you have).

Depending on how far you want to go, you can check if the customer has previous orders, or other stuff like that (maybe the billing/shipping address), since anyone who creates multiple accounts can cast a vote and get a new coupon.

Comment: I ended up creating the module as you said, but the coupon is just an image to use in the actual store, not in the site. Thanks for your help!